# Can I initialize a gRPC reply message repeated field using regular C# classes?

Tags: c#, .net-core, grpc

I have a List<> of objects that a gRPC server method needs to return in the reply message.  Should I be able to assign this List<> to the 'repeated' field, or must I convert each instance from the C# class to the generated class, generated by gRPC??

Here's an example:

```
    void Foo(
        List<DocSources.CntyCoverage>     counties,  //regular C# classes
        List<DocServiceGRpc.CntyCoverage> grpcList)  //server-side gRPC generated 
    {
        //What I'd like to be able to to...
        var reply1 = new StateCoverageReply()  //gRPC generated reply message containing 'repeated'
        {  CountyCoverage = { counties }  };
            // Error CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert 
            // from 'DocSources.CntyCoverage' 
            //   to 'DocServiceGRpc.CntyCoverage'   

        //Using List of gRPC generated classes
        var reply2 = new StateCoverageReply()
        {  CountyCoverage = { grpcList }  };
    }
```

The proto file specifies a 'repeated' class, called CntyCoverage.
The underlying generated code defines the field in terms of DocService**GRpc**.CntyCoverage.

I was hoping not to pass generate classes around the project.

I am I overlooking something?  Why can't I construct the gRPC Reply message using C# classes??

Comment: Do you understand what the compiler error means? Do you know how to write an explicit or implicit conversion operator?

Comment: I can write a conversion operator.  In fact, I just did one for this.  I asked the question because I was surprised that the generated code didn't handle it - figured I was missing something.  Thanks

Comment: Please share a [mcve].